# Nasm Assembly: I'm trying to copy a string and then search for a specific word in it, change it, and print it. Stuck on the copying part.

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, nasm

I'm stuck at figuring out to copy the string source to target, which should be initialized to all zeroes. It appears as though I need to find the size of the string, start a counter register, and push stringitem[counter] to the stack, increment counter register. I can't figure out how to even get started, let alone search for a word in the string.

Thanks!

```
    bits 64
    global main
    extern printf

    section .text
main:
    ; function setup
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    ;
    lea     rdi, [rel message]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
;
    lea     rdi, [rel source]
    mov     al, 0
    call    printf
;

    ;mov edi, source
    ;mov esi, target

    ;lea     rdi, [esi]
    ;mov     al, 0
    ;call    printf


    ;mov    ecx,sizeof source -1

;   mov esi,0

;L1:

;   mov     eax,source[esi];    
;   push    eax             
;   inc esi
;   loop    L1



    ; function return
    mov     eax, 0
    add     rsp, 32
    pop     rbp
    ret

    section .data
message: db      'Project',0x0D,0x0a,'Author',0x0D,0x0a,0
source:  db  0x0D,0x0a,"I can't figure out how to copy this text to target.",0x0D,0x0a,0
target:  db '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',0x0D,0x0a,0
```

Comment: You don't need the length and you definitely don't need the stack ... just copy each byte one by one and stop when you hit the zero. Easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your data memory layout this will do

```
lea rdi, [rel target]
lea rsi, [rel source]
mov rcx, target-source
cld
rep movsb
```

Otherwise as Jester said, a simple byte-to-byte copy will also do

```
    lea rdi, [rel target]
    lea rsi, [rel source]
    cld
.copy:
    lodsb
    stosb
    test al, al
    jnz .copy
```